# How to reroute electrical cables when eliminating void space that has been used for routing them?

Tags: electrical, framing, renovation

I want to incorporate the space from a laundry chute into a gut job of an adjacent bathroom.  Over the years electricians have used the disused chute as a raceway for wiring from the basement to the 2nd floor.  There are about 8 electrical cables running through it.

After ripping out the chute I'll be left with these cables running vertically through what will be my bathroom space.  I need to bury them in the adjacent walls.

I think the available approaches are:

1. Run them all into notches in the sills and joists as they pass through the new bathroom walls.   They may not need to pass through joists as they run vertically but I won't know for sure til it's all ripped open.  They may not have enough slack to do this, in which case it would not be an option.
2. Pull them out, all the way from the breaker panel to the second floor, then re-run them through holes drilled in the sills and joists.
3. Cut them so I can run them through holes without ripping them out entirely back to the panel, then splice them back in a big junction box in the wall that would have to be exposed to the adjacent bedroom.
4. Cut them just above or below the new bathroom, rather than in it, so the new junction box can be exposed in a wall in one of the rooms above or below, rather than the adjacent bedroom.

I don't know if (1) using notches is allowed.

(2) Ripping all these cables out back to the panel will be a ton of work disrupting several other rooms.

It seems cutting and splicing them is the best solution.  I think I have an inconspicuous place to expose the junction box cover in the room above the bathroom so I won't have to have it in the bedroom.   I may need two junction boxes if there's not enough slack in the cable.   This seems like a mess to me but is it the best solution?

IDK if this helps/matters but it's an 1896 construction with hugely oversized framing by today's standards.  Theoretically I can get away with notches and holes in excess of what today's code specifies, although I doubt that today's code would provide an exception for that so it's probably not of much use.

Any ideas/pointers/warnings?

Comment: Not sure what's code in your area but this will help https://www.familyhandyman.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2070002-how-joists-work.jpg?resize=1024,810

Comment: You can notch but nail plates will be needed. With that many cables any inspector I have ever had would flag for bundling unless 4 separate holes were drilled.